# Remove duplicates and merge row A

Tags: excel

I have a xls-sheet with many rows that have all unique content except for one content in one column. I want to merge the rows with duplicate content in columns B to D and combine content of column A in one cell:

```
100; boston; 1 newbury street; usa    
201; boston; 1 newbury street; usa    
302; boston; 1 newbury street; usa
```

============================

```
[100,201,302], boston, newbury street, usa
```

**Do you see a solution for this?**

Comment: It will require vba.

Comment: Or you can do it manually by copying and pasting the other columns, remove duplicates, then use an array form of TEXTJOIN() if you have it.

Comment: Then I have to try it the manual way since I don't have any knowledge about vba. Thank you!